# Can't connect to phpmyadmin in Bitnami instance hosted by AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin, bitnami

I'm trying to connect to phpmyadmin through my Public DNS and I can't seem to get it to work.

I've tried following these directions:

[Can't Access PHPMyAdmin](http://bitnami.com/forums/forums/bitnami-cloud/topics/can-t-access-phpmyadmin)

> By default phpMyAdmin is restricted to localhost. If you want it to be
>   accessible from anywhere you should follow the steps described in “How
>   to enable phpMyAdmin or phpPgAdmin?” in virtual machines FAQ:
>
> SSH to the instance Replace the line “Allow from 127.0.0.1” with
>   “Allow from all” in the file
>   /opt/bitnami/apps/phpmyadmin/conf/phpmyadmin.conf Restart apache: sudo
>   /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache

The problem with this solution is that I don't have a phpmyadmin.conf file in that directory.  I found this pertaining to that [Phpmyadmin.conf does not exist in the phpmyadmin folder](http://community.bitnami.com/t/phpmyadmin-conf-does-not-exist-in-the-phpmyadmin-folder/14293/5), but that didn't allow me to access.

> Check the /opt/bitnami/apps/phpmyadmin/htdocs/config.inc.php and
>   change the “$cfg[‘PmaAbsoluteUri’]” option with your URL.

I'm still getting the same `For security reasons, this URL is only accesible using localhost (127.0.0.1) as the hostname` error and it's driving me mad.

Any ideas?  If needed, I can readily post relevant content from configuration files.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

When looking at this article ([How to enable phpMyAdmin or phpPgAdmin to be accessed remotely?](http://wiki.bitnami.com/Components/phpMyAdmin_and_phpPgAdmin#How_to_enable_phpMyAdmin_or_phpPgAdmin_to_be_accessed_remotely.3f)), I needed to be looking at **Virtual Machine** and not **Amazon cloud / Bitnami Hosting**.

When I changed the `/opt/bitnami/apps/phpmyadmin/conf/httpd-app.conf` file to the following, I was able to access via [PUBLIC_DNS/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/IP]/phpmyadmin].

**Main changes being:**

> ```
> Allow from all
> ```

and

> ```
> Require all granted
> ```

After the changes, **remember to restart apache server**. (or reboot your instance)

> sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache

***/opt/bitnami/apps/phpmyadmin/conf/httpd-app.conf***

```
<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/phpmyadmin/htdocs">
# AuthType Basic
# AuthName phpMyAdmin
# AuthUserFile "/opt/bitnami/apache2/users"
# Require valid-user
AllowOverride None

<IfModule php5_module>
        php_value upload_max_filesize 80M
php_value post_max_size 80M
</IfModule>

<IfVersion < 2.3 >
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Satisfy all
</IfVersion>
<IfVersion >= 2.3>
Require all granted
</IfVersion>
ErrorDocument 403 "For security reasons, this URL is only accesible using localhost (127.0.0.1) as the hostname"
</Directory>
```

Docs Ref: https://docs.bitnami.com/virtual-machine/components/phpmyadmin/

Comment: So in the end, the two changes needed for me were:
--> Allow from all
--> Require all granted

Comment: your solution does not work, it is still "ErrorDocument 403 "For security reasons, this URL is only accessible using localhost (127.0.0.1) as the hostname."

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same issue. Though I was able to access phpMyAdmin by using the following steps

1. SSH to the server using the following command

   ssh -N -L 8888:127.0.0.1:80 -i YourPemFile.pem bitnami@YourServerIP
2. Then open the following link in your browser

   http://127.0.0.1:8888/phpmyadmin
3. You will see the following page
   [image]
4. Now just use root and the default wordpress password to login.

Comment: Thanks for this, worked great for me. The one exception is that even though I used 127.0.0.1 in the SSH command, I had to access the site through: http://localhost:8888/phpmyadmin/ (although 127.0.0.1 and localhost are equivalent it only worked with localhost...)

Comment: Same on my mac @MillerMedia. Had to use localhost

Comment: How to change the default Alias of the phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 1):

You should also restart your AWS server after you edited the http-app.conf .[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of restarting the server you can just type this on SSH:

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart
```